# Return this: (Params of __init__ method, names of attributes created in the __init__ method)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Per the snippet below, contrary to convention, the attributes of the Person Class do not share the same name as the parameters passed to the `__init__` method.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname,address):
        self.onoma = name
        self.diefthynsi = adress
        self.eponymo = surname
```

I would like ideally to view a list of tuples each with the parameter of `__init__` and the corresponding Name of the attribute given to an instance of the Person class. Like this:

```
(name, onoma), (surname, eponymo), (address, diefthynsi)
```

Comment: There is no inherent reason for there to be *any* connection between the parameters to `.__init__()` and the attributes of the class.  Any such connection is due solely to the code in that method; reading and understanding that code would be the only way to know about them.  The attributes certainly do not maintain any history as to where their values came from.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes can come from __dict__, try this:

```
import types

def get_attributes(obj):
    """
    Type of attributes is function, lambda or method not included.
    If required, you can add more types to exclude.
    """
    result = tuple(
        (value, key) for (key, value) in obj.__dict__.items()
            if type(value) not in
                (types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType, types.MethodType))
    return result

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, address):
        self.onoma = name
        self.diefthynsi = address
        self.eponymo = surname

    def help(self):
        pass

Sophia = Person('Sophia', 'Loren', 'ITALY')

print(get_attributes(Sophia))

# (('Sophia', 'onoma'), ('ITALY', 'diefthynsi'), ('Loren', 'eponymo'))
```